# How are minions affected by a blast?

Tags: minion, genesys

With minions I know that if I have 5 soak, 5 wound threshold minions in a group of 3 that if I have a single attack doing 11 damage....I kill 1 and 1 has 4 wounds left.

Now though if those minions are only in a single range band...what happens if I hit them with a 10 damage blast? Is only 1 killed or all of them?

Answer (score 2):

### Blast damage is calculated individually and applied collectively.

A Blast effect damages everyone in the blast. If that's all the minions, then it's all the minions, but it doesn't have to be - some can be in and some can be out. Calculate the Blast damage against all minions individually, then apply it collectively as normal.

Assuming no damage from a direct hit, just the Blast effect, a Blast 10 against 3 5/5 minions does (10 - 5) * 3 = 15 damage, enough to take everyone out.

A Blast 9 would do (9 - 5) * 3 = 12 damage, enough to drop 2.

A Blast 6 would do (6 - 5) * 3 = 3 damage, not enough to drop 1.

Do note that it doesn't make a lot of sense to kill minions who aren't actually in Blast range this way, but honestly? If you said that the blowthrough from a Blast 20 against one 5/5 minion on one side of a ship is going to Strain the other two minions that have chased somebody over to the other side of the ship and they surrender, I wouldn't call the RPG cops on you.